# Add empty links from a BreadcrumbBuilder

Tags: 8, navigation, breadcrumbs

For several specific parts of a website, I'm using a custom `BreadcrumbBuilder`, like this:

```
...
class SpecificBreadcrumbBuilder implements BreadcrumbBuilderInterface
{    
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match)
    {
        $node = $route_match->getParameter('node');
        return $node->getType() == 'specificpage';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match)
    {
        $node = $route_match->getParameter('node');

        $breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
        $breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(["url"]);
        $breadcrumb->addCacheTags(["node:{$node->nid->value}"]);

        $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute('Home', '<front>'));

        if (!empty($node->field_specific->value == '...')) {
          $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute('Specific pages', '<front>'));
          $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($node->getTitle(), '<front>'));
        }

        return $breadcrumb;
    }
}
```

I would like to **not** use URLs for the two last links. Something like `<nolink>` (from the "Special Menu Items" module), but made from code.
I cannot find a way to add a text-only element to my Breadcrumb (and from what I can see, this class only have an `addLink()` function).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 8 has now a special `<nolink>` route to define empty links:

```
$breadcrumb->addlink(Link::createFromRoute('Empty link', '<nolink>'));
```

See issue (patch commited to 8.2.x): https://www.drupal.org/node/2693725

Comment: Thanks! I searched for it, but may have use `<none>` of something else.